# How do I remove a table that I programmed in?

Tags: html, html-table

I have used this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table Time</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
            </tr>
                <td>Two</td>
            <tr>
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

To create a table. How can I remove the table using code? Will I have to declare a variable for the table using "id" or will I have to do something else, and what is the line of code to remove a table. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you want to remove the table based on some type of user interaction, correct?

Comment: By "code" do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct Jordan. @JordanDavis

Comment: Probably Javascript, unless there is a simpler inbulit function in HTML or php. @j08691

Comment: @Paldox okay I'll create a demo for you based of a user button click to remove the table in pure JavaScript so its very easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JS solution:

```
var el = document.getElementById("tableID");
el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
```

[Functional CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgwrMN)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your `table` has an ID of `tableID`.

Using `jQuery`:

```
$("#tableID").remove();
```

Using `Javascript`:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
table.parentNode.removeChild(table);
```

Comment: What about Javascript or php? Or can I introduce jQuery with <jQuery> or something similar?

Comment: @Paldox I added a snippet for when you're just wanting to use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

One common method would be to create a wrapper for the table, and then replace the inner HTML of the wrapper with your new HTML. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="table-wrapper">
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
            </tr>
                <td>Two</td>
            <tr>
                <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
       <button type="button" id="button">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#button').click(function () {
                 $('#table-wrapper').html('No records found.');
             });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the corresponding JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/ws0j3xma/

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the link to the **JSFiddleDemo**](https://jsfiddle.net/13vjub9g/1/)

It's not required but its best practice would be to format your table using `thead`,`tbody`,`th` tags.

//HTML

```
<body>
   <table id='mytable'>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Table Head 1</th>
         <th>Table Head 2</th>
         <th>Table Head 3</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
         <td>Data 3</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Data 1</td>
         <td>Data 2</td>
         <td>Data 3</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <button id='mybutton'>Remove Table</button>
</body>
```

//JS

```
//WHEN THE DOCUMENT LOADS RUN THIS FUNCTION 
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
        var btn = document.getElementById('mybutton'); //GET THE BUTTON AND SET IT TO A VARIABLE IN JS
        btn.addEventListener('click', removeTable);  //ADD A 'CLICK' EVENT LISTENERS, WHEN THE USER CLICKS IT WILL RUN THE FUNCTION 'removeTable'
    }
}
function removeTable(){
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable'); //GET THE TABLE SET TO VARIABLE IN JS
  document.body.removeChild(table); //REMOVE THE TABLE FROM THE DOCUMENT BODY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using jquery you can use javascript

add this to your head

```
<script>
    function hidetable(which){
    document.getElementById((which).style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

just add this to the element

```
<div onClick="hidetable('tablename')"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can **delete table with javascript** like this

```
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to remove the first row in the table.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a html button and give the table and the button id of your choosing, like

```
<button id="removeTableButton">Save</button>
<table border="1px" id="myTable">
<... rows and data ...>
</table>
```

At the bottom add a javascript file like func.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In func.js you can add an eventListener() that executes a function when you click on the button.

```
document.getElementById("removeTableButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    table.innerHtml = "";
});
```